# ActiveRecord: Column 'nivelAcceso' cannot be null

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I need to add a 'Change password' feature to the app I'm currently building, but when I try to change an user's password, I get the following error:

**Column 'nivelAcceso' cannot be null**; While the user's password and 'nivelAcceso' (the access the user has in the application) are found on the same table (usuarios) they aren't related in any way.

The route that handles the password change looks like this:

**app.rb**

```
put '/:id' do
change_password(params[:id], params[:password], params[:confirm])
end
```

While the controller looks like:

**password_controller.rb**

```
def change_password(id, password, confirm)
if password.nil? || confirm.nil?
redirect '/dashboard/change_password', error: 'Debe completar todos los campos.'
elsif password != confirm
redirect '/dashboard/change_password', error: 'Los campos no coinciden.'
else
u = User.find(id)

new_password = BCrypt::Password.create(password)

u.passwordUsuario = new_password

if u.save
  redirect '/dashboard/change_password', notice: 'Cambio de contraseña exitoso.'
else
  redirect '/dashboard/change_password', error: 'Ha ocurrido un error, intente nuevamente.'
end
end
end
```

I have tried the following with no avail so far:

```
u.nivelAcceso = session[:rol] # 'nivelAcceso' value is stored in the session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the route to change the password is exactly the same as the route to edit an user.

**Original, non-working route**:

```
put '/:id' do
change_password(params[:id], params[:password], params[:confirm])
end
```

**Edited, working route**:

```
put '/change_password/:id' do
change_password(params[:id], params[:password], params[:confirm])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord says the column can't be null. This is usually due to the database being configured this way.

If you configured the database using ActiveRecord migrations, look for something like this:

```
create_table(:cars) do |t|
  # other commands
  t.string :foo, null: false
end
```

You can change this by writing and running a new migration:

```
change_column :table_name, :foo_column, :string, null: true
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. This didn't work. It only cleared the 'nivelAcceso' for the user that tried to change the password, but helped me to find where the error was. Thanks!